# Set COMPATIBILITY LEVEL by passing value as local variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, compatibility

I am trying to get this code snipp working.

*Targeting SQL 2005 SP2 and newer SQL Server products.*

Code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @level tinyint;
DECLARE @levelvar tinyint;
IF substring(@@VERSION, 23, 4) != '2000'
BEGIN
  select @level = [compatibility_level] from sys.databases where name = DB_name();
  SET @levelvar = @level;
  EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel ":DATABASE_NAME" @level;
END;
```

Yes, it the `@levelvar` is not necessary, yes, I could use `DB_name()` also in `sp_dbcmptlevel`, yes, I could use `ALTER TABLE` and yes, the `IF` returns wrong value in SQL 2012, but the pain is that It simply cannot be executed in SQL Studio. The error message is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '@level'.
```

How to get the local variable `@level` / `@levelvar` passed to this stored procedure?

Comment: Is `:DATABASE_NAME` coming from SQLCMD mode? Otherwise I don't quite understand how this will ever execute. Also why are you getting the current compatibility level and setting the database to the same thing? Is this like `UPDATE dbo.table SET col = col;`?

Comment: Also can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, Aaron, for your support, but the need is not pretty important here. It was simply my curvehands.dll recently updated, when writing this small statement, so I somehow did not see missing comma and END. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two syntax errors in your code snippet. A missing comma in the call to sp_dbcmptlevel, and a missing END for the outer block BEGIN. This version compiles for me:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @level tinyint;
    DECLARE @levelvar tinyint;
    IF SUBSTRING(@@VERSION, 23, 4) != '2000'
    BEGIN
      SELECT @level = [compatibility_level] FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME();
      SET @levelvar = @level;
      EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel ":DATABASE_NAME", @level;
    END;
END;
```